# is it possible dynamic switch theme in codemirror6

Tags: codemirror-6

I want to switch the codemirror6 theme, now I do it like this:

```
if (projConf.confYype == ProjConfType.Theme) {
        const currentTheme = themeMap.get(projConf.confValue);
        if (currentTheme) {
          if (!activeEditorView) return;
          var theme = new Compartment;
          activeEditorView.dispatch({
            effects: theme.reconfigure(currentTheme)
          });
        }
      }
```

first I stored the theme in a map<string,theme>, and get the theme by name, set the theme into the editorView. But the codemirror6 theme did not changed, am I missing something? I am inspired from this question https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/how-to-change-editor-theme-dinamically/4173/5 from codemirror6 community.